# Matching ClassTag with another field in a case class

Tags: scala, reflection

Is there a way I can make following piece of code work? Expected result is that one of the promises in the list will be completed (the one with matching String type).

```
import scala.concurrent.Promise
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

case class Test[T](promise: Promise[T], tag: ClassTag[T])

def createTest[T](implicit tag: ClassTag[T]) = Test(Promise[T](), tag)

val seq: Seq[Test[_]] = Seq(createTest[String], createTest[Int])

seq.foreach { case Test(promise, tag) =>
  "asd" match {
    case tag(s) => promise.success(s)
    case _ => // nothing
  }
}
```

currently it yields the error:

> found   : s.type (with underlying type Any)
>
> required: _$1 where type _$1

Comment: what's "asd" and why are you comparing that with the classTag?

Comment: so "asd" is just a String, basically I want to use ClasTag similar way to:

def getMessage[T](implicit tag: ClassTag[T]): Option[T] = message match {
    case tag(msg) => Some(msg)
    case _ => None
  }

this works just fine, but when I try to do it "indirectly" (example from my question) it does not

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution using `Class` instead of `ClassTag`:

```
import scala.concurrent.Promise

case class Test[T](promise: Promise[T], clazz: Class[T])

def createTest[T](clazz: Class[T]) = Test(Promise[T](), clazz)

val seq: Seq[Test[_]] = Seq(createTest[String](classOf[String]), createTest[Int](classOf[Int]))

seq.foreach { case Test(promise, clazz) =>
  val obj = "asd"
  if (clazz.isInstance(obj)) promise.success(clazz.cast(obj))  
}
```